# Length and circumference of circle

Tags: geometry

Can we call length of a circle its circumference? Can $L$ of circle $=2 \pi r$?

There are some teachers who used to say to cut a rope and encircle a circle completely and then stretch it out straight and measure the length of rope with a measuring tape to find the circumference of a circle.

Comment: What is your question, actually ?

Answer (score 1):

For [suitably well behaved curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) in the plane, the *length of the curve* is defined.

If the curve is closed, that is, its starting point and ending point coincide, the length of this curve is sometimes called *the circumference of the closed curve*. A circle is just a special example.

The picture with the rope is meant to convey that the circle can be "cut" at a point and then unbent in such a way so that the length of the curved line is not changed. Measuring the straight, unbent piece of rope is therefore measuring the original circle's circumference.